# Can a function without an argument be called with an argument in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out what this piece of code is doing, and how this is working. How is let foo = require('foo') being called when it doesn't take any argument?

foo.js

```
module.export = async () => { do something and return response(200) }
```

bar.js

```
let foo = require('foo')
module.exports = {
  foo: async (req) => { return foo(req) }
}
```

route.js

```
let api = required('api')
let bar = required('bar')
module.exports = api => {
  api.get('/foo', async req => await bar.foo(req))
}
```

Comment: Would reading the docs for `require` explain it? I see arguments.

Comment: foo.js is returning async function which doesn't have any argument defined. so How does `let foo` get used? Does JS do method override?

Comment: It passes an argument that is never used. That is fine in JS.

Comment: Ohhh, got it! Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR:

Yes, it is allowed.

### How it works

All functions in js have access to a local variable called `arguments`. The `arguments` variable is an array-like object (something that looks like an array but is not an instance of the `Array` class) containing all arguments passed to the function. This is basically the js mechanism supporting variable arguments.

Example:

```
function a () {
    for (x=0; x<arguments.length); x++) {
        console.log(arguments[x]);
    }
}
```

In addition to allowing you to pass more arguments than what's defined by a function js also allows you to pass fewer arguments that what's required by a function. The arguments that you don't pass are simply given the value of `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it thoroughly! very helpful!